# how to block users who log in without registration to php and database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
$submit=$_POST['submit'];
$firstName=strip_tags($_POST['firstName']);
$lastName=strip_tags($_POST['lastName']);
$email=strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$username=strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$password=strip_tags($_POST['password']);
$DateTime=strip_tags($_POST['DateTime']);


if ($submit)
{
 //open Database
 $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
 mysql_select_db("mitch"); 
//select database
 
 $namecheck = mysql_query ("SELECT username FROM tbmitch WHERE username='$username'");
 $count = mysql_num_rows($namecheck);

 if ($count!=0)
 {
  
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Control number already exists')</script>";  
 }
 
 //check for existence
 else
 if($username)
  {
 
 $queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbmitch VALUES ('$username','$lastName','$firstName','$email','$password',now())");
  
 $_SESSION['username']=$username;   
   header('location:home.php'); 
   
   echo '
   <script type="text/javascript">alert("Record/s saved.");
   window.location.href = "home.php";
   </script>';
   
     
  }
 
 else 
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Please fill in all fields')</script>";  

}
?>



<html>
 <head>
  <title>MobileApp-SignUp</title>
<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/960_12_col.css" />
  <style>
   * {
    font-family: Georgia;
    color: black;
    text-align: top;
    font-size: 16px;}
   li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px;}
   ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #b5c1ad;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #4EE2EC;}
   a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;}
   a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;}
   header {
    text-align: right;}
   
    
  </style>
  
  
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/form.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formatTextArea(textArea) {
        textArea.value = textArea.value.replace(/(^|\r\n|\n)([^*]|$)/g, "$1*$2");
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        var textArea = document.getElementByusername("t");
        textArea.onkeyup = function(evt) {
            evt = evt || window.event;

            if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
                formatTextArea(this);
            }
        };
    };
</script>


 </head>
<center>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
  <div class="container_12 clearfix">
   <div username="header" class="grusername_12">
    
    <img src = "images/img.gif" height="200" width="200" border="3" align="center"></p>
    <div username="nav" style="width:450">
    
     <ul>
      <li><a href="home.php">Back to Home</a>|</li>
      <br>
      <br>
      <img src="images/header.gif" width="95" class="logo" /><br>
      <img src="images/underheader.gif" width="75" class="logo" />
     </ul>
     
     
    </div>
   </div>
   <span class="right">
     <?php echo "&nbsp;&nbsp; Welcome ".$_SESSION['UserID']." |"; ?>
                </span>

</head>
</body>
<br>


  
  <style type="text/css">
   body {
    background-image: url("bg/bgcloud.jpeg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color: black;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Georgia;}
   p {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: red;}
   p.ab {
    color: black;}
   .button {
    padding: 7px 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #7FE817;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px #999;}
   .button:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;}
   


</style>
<body>
<p class = "ab">[Signup to check your Cacao plant]</p>
<p class = "ab">Signup here <p>&#8595 &#8595; &#8595; &#8595; &#8595; &#8595;</p>
<br>
<br>
<form action="done.php" method="post">
   <div>
    <label for="name" class="title">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" username="firstName" name="firstNamename" size="30" name='firstName' maxlength="100" required="required"/>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div>
    <label for="name" class="title">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" username="lastName" name="lastName" size="30" name='lastName' maxlength="100" required="required"/>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div>
    <label for="email" class="title">E-mail add:</label>
    <input type="email" username="email" name="email" size="30" name='email' maxlength="100" required="required"/>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="radio-buttons">
    <span class="title" required="required">Gender:</span>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" username="male" value="M" />
    <label for="male">M</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" username="female" value="F" />
    <label for="female">F</label><br />
   </div>
   <br>
   <br>
   <div>
   <p>*the next entry must be remembered for logging in*</p>
   <label for="username">Username:</label>
   <input type="text" name="username" required="required" size="20" name='username' maxlength="100"/></title><br />
   <br>
   <label for="password">Password :</label>
   <input type="password" name="password" required="required" size="20" name='password' maxlength="100" />
   <br>
   <br>
   
   <a href="done.php"><button class="button"><span>Submit</span></button></a>
  
  </div>
  
  </form>


</body>


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p class = "ab" align="right">
 &#169; 2017 BSCT-2B MobileApp
</p>
</form>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm into PHP and I find it difficult to pass my files to mysql database (I'm using the xampp here, if that helps), I want to do signups on my site and later log in to the registered data, if I;m referring to other users I want to block users who haven't register themselves on the database first, so how do I do it? What to change?

Comment: too broad. post your source code for help

Comment: That is why you have Login pages. Invalid credentials would make the user stay on login page itself. This is the same as what you are referring as "block users who log in without registration". This is what I understood from your question

Comment: This is probably the most thoroughly discussed topic in the internet

Comment: I wanted to save the data that are registered, and if they log in already, they have to be registered.

Comment: Thanks for saying that, it helps really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP + mySql based application we can have web pages for authenticated users only, and to achieve that we need to do following steps:

1. Create Login Form.
2. On submit validate the data submitted through form and if it return true (Valid login credential). Create a $_SESSION variable to identify logged in user.
3. While rendering any webpage which requires authenticated user only, check for that particular $_SESSION variable.
4. It valid $_SESSION exists, show the page, else redirect it to the login page.

Hope this helps.